# Wireless routers as Access point using LAN-LAN but no connectivity through other LAN ports, and wifi works

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I have followed every single step given in following page of DD-WRT page to setup a wireless access point.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point

I have a belkin G router and a tp-link 841N router having dd wrt installed.

From belkin LAN port i ran a cable to tp-link router and configured every single step perfectly and double checked making tp-link router as Access point.

After switching on the routers and laptop and mobiles connected are working fine and able to access internet.

But from the tp-link router if i connected any device to other lan ports then those devices are unable to access the network. They are not even getting ip assigned. Even if i manually add the ip they are still unable to access.

But as per the steps given in dd wrt page it should work properly.

Main router has channel 11 and tp-link has channel 6 for wireless.

Here are the network settings of the tp-link router.
[image: Setup_Basic_Settings]
[image: Setup_Advanced_Routing]
[image: Wireless_Basic_Settings]

Comment: On the tlink router did you plug the cable into the WAN port or one of the LAN ports.

Comment: I plugged in to LAN port... I did LAN-LAN connection...

Comment: Ok that is what I understand to be correct, but since you didn't say that specifically above I asked.

Comment: Screenshots of your network settings please. And it's **TP**-Link, not "tlink"

Comment: Sorry was little late.. i have updated with screenshots of wireless settings.

Comment: On tplink enable dhcp forwarder and point to belkin's DHCP server.

Comment: Where can i find this dhcp forwarder?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your network diagram I have a similar setup in place.

Router 1 {R1} - Router 2 {R2}

R1: Asus Tomato USB: DHCP provider

R2: Tp link Factory: Separate DHCP or Act as Switch

- Separate DHCP - Provides its own DHCP and separate Local IP addressing

  - Connections: `R1: LAN - R2: WAN - R2: LAN - Clients`
  - PS: Check for IP address, DHCP & Gateway obtained from R2 by running ipconfig
- Act as Switch - Depends on DHCP from R1 with common Local IP addressing

  - Connections: `R1: LAN - R2: LAN - Clients`
  - Apparently on your FW you can also assign WAN port as a Switch so no
    NAT happens.
  - PS: Check for IP address, DHCP & Gateway obtained from R1 by running ipconfig

Note: DHCP from R1 will forward by default, or one has to ensure that DHCP from R1 is not blocked or disabled by R2 which is acting as a switch.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration surely has **at least one error**: the static IP address you assign to your AP, `192.168.1.101` falls within the IP address pool of ... `itself`: from your configuration mask in fact  we see that the IP address pool starts at `192.168.1.100`! This alone is enough tto compromise the working of your TP-Link AP.

I suggest you correct the above as follows:

1. Under Setup -> Basic Setup-> DHCP Type, choose, in the drop-down curtain, **DHCP Forwarder**. This disables the DHCP server on the DD-WRT machine, something the instructions you referred to were adamant about.
2. Under Setup -> Advanced Routing -> Operating mode, choose **Gateway** in the drop-down curtain. Your TP-Link is **not** a router, the Belkin machine is.

There is another point: this is a warning, more than a key difference. Under Setup -> Basic Setup -> Wan Connection Type, I'd rather you choose **Automatic Configuration -DHCP**. The advantage of this is that, this way, you are **sure** the IP of the DD-WRT router does not conflict with any address within the lease range of the DHCP server on the Belkin Router. I will not suggest you change this at all costs, even though it would be way safer, but **please** do make extra sure `192.168.1.101` is **not** within the IP pool of the Belkin router.

You ought to set the above options, then **reboot** the router, and try again to see whether the wired clients of the TP-Link get an IP address, and then can communicate with the WAN.

Comment: These are all good suggestions, but likely none of them explains the problem the OP is having.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  I do not know for sure, but I suspect that IP address conflicts, which surely cause all sorts of strange behavior, may even be responsible for **this** problem, especially if the AP IP address falls within the router's IP address pool.

Comment: No it does not fall... I have set the main routers ip range from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.100

Comment: @Sandeep Which is  a msitake because 192.168.1.100 is the beginning of the DHCP range of the DD-WRT....  Does it work after the modifications I suggested,  or is there still some problem?

Comment: @marius, did you not see the op was trying to bridge the two routers? Wan enabled on dd-wrt = NAT.